# How to Add Line between two UIView centers in Swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview, uibezierpath, cgpoint

**As you can see in the Image attached, there are red and green Views on the screen, I want to add a Line between them. How can I do that?**
[image]

Comment: add a uiview with width 1

Comment: Ya, That could work...but below answer is a more elegant way of Handling this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  func addLine(fromPoint start: CGPoint, toPoint end:CGPoint) {
    let line = CAShapeLayer()
    let linePath = UIBezierPath()
    linePath.move(to: start)
    linePath.addLine(to: end)
    line.path = linePath.cgPath
    line.strokeColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
    line.lineWidth = 1
    line.lineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.round
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(line)
}
```

Usage: - `addLine(fromPoint: yourFirstView.center, toPoint: yourSecondView.center)`

Make sure your views are accessible while calling this function